# I have to use sudo to edit every file - no permissions to do anything

Tags: permissions, sudo, files

I need to execute every command with `sudo` proceeding it and I can't edit any text file without running gedit with `sudo gedit`, even files I've created myself.

I just want to be able to open a project folder in Atom and be able to save the files but I can't seem to be able to do it.

running `ls -al` in the home directory results in:

```
drwxr-xr-x 25 {me}        {me} 4096 nov 13 23:56 .
drwxr-xr-x  3 root        root        4096 okt 31 18:14 ..
-rw-rw-r--  1         700 {me}  840 nov  1 01:42 .alsaequal.bin
drwxrwxr-x  7         700 {me} 4096 nov 13 23:57 .atom
-rw-------  1         700 {me} 7422 nov 13 23:48 .bash_history
-rw-r--r--  1         700 {me}  220 okt 31 18:14 .bash_logout
-rw-r--r--  1         700 {me} 3771 okt 31 18:14 .bashrc
drwx------ 21         700 {me} 4096 nov  9 18:02 .cache
drwx------  3         700 {me} 4096 okt 31 21:02 .compiz
drwx------ 23         700 {me} 4096 nov 13 23:56 .config
drwx------  3         700 root        4096 nov  1 00:26 .dbus
drwxr-xr-x  6         700 {me} 4096 nov  9 23:38 Desktop
-rw-r--r--  1         700 {me}   25 nov  5 17:03 .dmrc
-rw-rw-r--  1         700 {me}   54 nov  5 14:15 Dockerfile
drwxr-xr-x  2         700 {me} 4096 okt 31 19:36 Documents
drwxr-xr-x  3         700 {me} 4096 nov 10 20:28 Downloads
-rw-r--r--  1         700 {me} 8980 okt 31 18:14 examples.desktop
drwx------  2         700 {me} 4096 nov 13 21:30 .gconf
rw-r------  1         700 {me}    0 nov 13 23:57 .gksu.lock
drwx------  3         700 {me} 4096 nov  5 17:01 .gnome
drwx------  3         700 {me} 4096 nov 13 22:28 .gnupg
-rw-------  1         700 {me} 9576 nov 13 22:28 .ICEauthority
drwx------  5         700 {me} 4096 nov  8 16:31 .local
drwx------  4         700 {me} 4096 okt 31 18:37 .mozilla
drwxr-xr-x  2         700 {me} 4096 okt 31 19:36 Music
drwxrwxr-x  2         700 {me} 4096 nov  5 23:26 .nano
drwx------  3         700 {me} 4096 nov  1 01:26 .nv
-rw-rw-r--  1         700 {me}  642 nov  6 00:01 .nvidia-settings-rc
drwxr-xr-x  2         700 {me} 4096 okt 31 19:36 Pictures
drwx------  3         700 {me} 4096 nov  5 17:01 .pki
-rw-r--r--  1         700 {me}  655 okt 31 18:14 .profile
drwxr-xr-x  2         700 {me} 4096 okt 31 19:36 Public
drwxrwxr-x  3         700 {me} 4096 nov  5 14:13 qemu-static-    conf
drwx------  2         700 {me} 4096 nov  5 16:27 .ssh
-rw-r--r--  1         700 {me}    0 okt 31 20:48     .sudo_as_admin_successful
drwxr-xr-x  2         700 {me} 4096 okt 31 19:36 Templates
drwxr-xr-x  2         700 {me} 4096 okt 31 19:36 Videos
-rw-------  1         700 {me}   57 nov 13 22:28 .Xauthority
-rw-------  1         700 {me}   82 nov 13 22:28 .xsession-errors
-rw-------  1         700 {me}   82 nov 10 21:09 .xsession-errors.old
```

Comment: What happens when you try to do something without sudo?

Comment: I can't do most things unless I use sudo, it will say I don't have permissions

Comment: Please post the full error message.

Comment: What happens when you are in your home directory and you run `ls -al`?

Comment: I've updated my post to show the feedback from `ls -al` and one example of what happens is that when I try to save a change in Atom it says 'Permission denied; can't save file', same happens in gedit etc

Comment: NEVER use `sudo` with GUI tools. ALWAYS `sudo -H` (`sudo -H gedit` in this case). And you have permissions for files inside your userspace only; anywhere else is root's domain, hence the need to run with sudo.

Comment: OK, the permissions and ownership of your home dir look fine. Try running `ls -al` in the same directory as one of the files you are trying to edit.

Comment: @wjandrea are you sure? Looks like everything is owned by a user `700`, possibly the result of running `chown 700 something` instead of `chmod 700 something`

Comment: @Zanna Yes, you're right, I totally missed that.

Comment: I read online that you should use `gksudo` with GUI tools.. But in my experience that never worked because it would freeze within seconds. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently you ran something like (this is a dangerous command - **do not execute**!)

```
chown -R 700 *
```

making a probably non-existent user `700` owner of everything in your home directory. You may have been trying to apply the octal permissions 700 to your home directory with a command like (this is another dangerous command - **do not execute**!)

```
chmod -R 700 *
```

which would also be a really bad idea. Don't change permissions unless you're sure you know what you're doing. And beware the `-R` flag.

The reason I think you used the `-R` flag with `chown` is that hidden files were affected. But, you may have used `dotglob` and not used `-R`. If you didn't use `-R` originally, don't use it to revert the change.

It's possible that some files in your home directory should not be owned by you, but it's likely that they should. I suggest you `chown` your home directory.

If you did not use the `-R` (recursive) flag, then run these commands to change only the ownership of the top level files:

```bsh
shopt -s dotglob            # to work on hidden files
sudo chown $USER $HOME/*
shopt -u dotglob
```

If you used the `-R` flag to change the ownership of your home directory, use this command:

```
sudo chown -R $USER $HOME
```

---

As an aside, as mentioned in [a comment by Michael Bay](https://askubuntu.com/questions/976154/i-have-to-use-sudo-to-edit-every-file-no-permissions-to-do-anything/976272#976272), do not launch graphical applications like Gedit with `sudo <application>`, as this might cause root to become the owner of local config files. Use `sudo`'s `-H` flag to avoid this, eg `sudo -H gedit`.

Comment: Correct, I had a small permission problem in the beginning and I think I found a 'solution' on stackoverflow for that, but it just exacerbated the situation. I just started using Ubuntu because I needed it for a certain dev environment which would only run on Linux, so I'm quite the Linux novice. This fixed all permission issues! Thank a million! I have to say that Ubuntu isn't the most user friendly when setting it up for the first time, but once you get running it is really versatile.

Comment: Linux isn't user **Unfriendly**; It's just picky about who its friends are. 

It looks like you are off to a good start proving to Linux that you are a true friend. Welcome to the club.